connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
I have running postgresql docker container with next command  docker run -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust -v /var/lib/postgresql/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data postgis/postgis
pg_hba.conf file include next lines:
# warning trust is enabled for all connections
host all all all trust

Connection request from host machine: psql -h localhost -U fake
Response in DB logs: FATAL:  role "fake" does not exist
Test Dockerfile:
FROM postgres:latest
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y postgresql-client
CMD ["psql", "-U", "fake", "-h", "localhost", "-p", "5432"]

Test docker container failed with next error:

psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused
Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused
Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?

I don't see anything in DB logs.
Why I can't make a request from the test docker container?

The PostgreSQL container has CMD set to start the PostgreSQL server process. If you override CMD, it will no longer start the PostgreSQL server.

'localhost' in your test container refers to that container.  But the database is presumably running in some other container.

To connect two different docker containers I have to provide next parameter  --network="host".
Correct command would be docker run --network="host" test
